# L Sit back form is bad, back leaning forward rather than a strict straight one

Tags: calisthenics

How come when I L-sit my back is always bent forward? It doesn't feel necessarily painful but it does not feel right, and I heard that you should try to aim for a near strict back posture. My posture is almost completely leaning forward, any advice for fix? Is it just a mobility issue?

Answer (score 1):

A few explanations may be:

1. Your arms are too short

   - If your arms are not long enough to keep your body off the ground then your body is compensating
2. Your center of mass when you have a straight back is behind your arms

   - Your pelvis may be behind your arms and your upper body is drawn forward to balance it out
3. Your back is not strong enough

   - Your back isn't able to counteract the force of your abdomen contracting
4. Your lateral & posterior deltoids and lats may not be strong enough to support your shoulders holding you upright.

   - By rotating forward, your body is compensating with stronger anterior delts

If you haven't already, I would suggest video-taping yourself performing the L-sit from the side, and seeing if you can spot what fails first when performing the exercise.

Comment: The option you miss is that it could also be a mobility issue in the hamstrings / glutes, which causes a rounding in the back to create the L shape.

Comment: @MJB good one, i neglected stretching